# "flutter run" works on emulator, but fails on real device "getter 'statusCode' was called on null flutter"

Tags: php, android, laravel, flutter, android-emulator

I stumbled upon a problem when running my Flutter app on my real device. I tried running it with an emulator and it works just fine (i.e. it communicates with my localhost Laravel server), but upon running it on my phone/real device, Flutter just stops interacting with the localhost server altogether. Below is a snippet of my code.

```
Future<List> _login() async {
    if (user.text.isEmpty || pass.text.isEmpty) {
      Alert(context: context, title: "Incorrect Data", type: AlertType.error)
          .show();
    } else {
      final resp =
          await http.post("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/login", headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      }, body: {
        "username": user.text,
        "password": pass.text,
      }).catchError((error) {
        print(error);
      });

    // resp is null since the app doesn't make any request to the server, 
    // thus calling statusCode throws an error
    if (resp.statusCode != 200) { ... } else { ... }
}
```

I've made sure that `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` has been included in my AndroidManifest.xml and have been using 10.0.2.2 instead of the default 127.0.0.1, I've also made sure that the API's url works as intended using Postman. But it still gives me the same result. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank You!

Comment: I'm assuming your device is connected to the same router as the machine running the server and joined the same local area network?

Comment: hey, yes I also made sure that both my devices (physical phone & computer) are connected to the same network. Thank you for asking that!

Comment: Might be worth logging into your router and making sure both are on the same network. Sometimes routers will provide both a 2.4ghz and 5ghz WiFi network using the same network ID making it hard to distinguish which network you're actually on but those actually form different LANs (not saying it's the likely cause of the problem but it is a potential cause)

Comment: You should try by serving your application on your router's public IP address and connect your phone to the same network and then try to run the app it will work fine to get the router IP type ```ipconfig``` in terminal and run the command you'll get some info about the network just copy the IP address which labeled as ```ipv4``` and serve your backend in this IP and you can choose any port and use same IP and port for the app.